# How to make a debounce function act independently on different instances of the same component on Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, mixins, debouncing

I have two Vue components that have a "save to disk" call on every change of data, it is loaded into these components via a mixin and each component save into a different file, so they must function independently (only trigger a debounce reset on its own change of data). To prevent too much writing to the disk. Here's my debound function:

```
function debounce(fn, delay) {
  var timeoutID = null;
  return function () {
    console.log("clearing " + timeoutID)
    clearTimeout(timeoutID);
    var args = arguments;
    var that = this;
    timeoutID = setTimeout(() => fn.apply(that, args), delay);
  };
}
```

Here's the methods on my mixin that the components inherit:

```
  methods: {
    saveData: debounce(function(){
        console.log('saving widget: ' + this.$parent.widget.id);
        this.saver.store = this.persisted;
    }, 5000),
  },
```

It works well when I'm changing data on one or the other component, but when I change data on one and before debounce ends I change on the other, it cancels my debounce function from the first one, and only saves the second component data.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Probabily because you clear Timeout in the begin of you method. The `timeoutID` look like always null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because each component instance shares the same debounced function, only the context (`this`, `that`) is varying.

A simple workaround would be to change your debounce implementation to

```js
function debounce(fn, delay) {
  var thatUidToTimeoutID = {};
  return function () {
    var args = arguments;
    var that = this;
    clearTimeout(thatUidToTimeoutID[that._uid]);
    thatUidToTimeoutID[that._uid] = setTimeout(() => fn.apply(that, args), delay);
  };
}
```

`_uid` is holding an unique id of each component, it's more of an internal property (hence it's weird key) but it should be good enough.

Comment: makes sense.. since debounce is a global function on my case for multiple scenarios, what happens if I use this function outside of a vue component?

Comment: As for the version dependent on the `_uid` field, it depends on the context. If context is null, you'll get error saying `Can't read property _uid of undefined`, otherwise it will behave the same way as the original debounce function (assuming that `_uid` is undefined or an immutable string / number / boolean property, because all of them are valid keys in js object).

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered the same issue today. I've tried something else that is, in my opinion, a bit cleaner. Instead of defining the debounced function within the methods block like you did, try defining it as part of the data like so:

```
  data() {
   return {
    saveData: debounce(function(){
        console.log('saving widget: ' + this.$parent.widget.id);
        this.saver.store = this.persisted;
    }, 5000)
  }
 }
```

You can call the method the same way as you would normally. From the docs: "A component’s data option must be a function, so that each instance can maintain an independent copy of the returned data object." This way, each instance that uses the debounce function will have it's own unique instance of it.

More on how this works can be found here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function